# Programmatically Create Channel Tab (not from Configure popup)

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a use case where I would like to create a Channel/group tab, but from code -- not from the configure experience

Where?

- user in in a channel and a Task is popped up (via custom iFrame)
- user selects an item from this iFrame, and a new Tab is created in that channel, pointing (Deeplinking?) to that content
- The channel may not have a Tab created; I can see how you get the current Tabs for a channel in `microsoftTeams.js`

(ie: `microsoftTeams.getTabInstances(callback: (tabInfo: TabInformation),tabInstanceParameters?: TabInstanceParameters,)`)

- but there is no mechanism either in `microsoftTeams.js` -or- Microsoft Graph to create a new Tab in that channel

I attempted to use

`microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink(deepLink: string, onComplete?: (status: boolean, reason?: string))`

with an appropriately formatted `deepLink` but it silently failed

My code works OK from the `"configurableTabs": [` experience

Thoughts? Missing feature?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [Add Tab to channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamstab-add?view=graph-rest-1.0) using Graph API.