# Is it possible to programmatically (e.g. using Graph) add a Tab to a Chat

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I know that I can use the Graph (Beta endpoint) to [add a Tab to a **Channel** inside a Team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamstab-add?view=graph-rest-1.0), but I can't see in the docs a way to add to a ***Chat*** programmatically. The "Who" bot seems able to do this somehow (I assume using some internal mechanism), but is there something available to us to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59079908/programmatically-create-channel-tab-not-from-configure-popup

Comment: Thanks Nick, That's basically what I linked to, but I realised now my question was maybe a little unclear, so I've reworded it - I'm trying to add the tab to a -chat-, and NOT a -channel-.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, This not supported right now.

Comment: ok thanks. Is it on a list somewhere I could add a vote to? I seem to think there was a uservoice, but for dev/api requests somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no Graph API available to add tab to chat, However we have this in our roadmap but we don't have ETA to share it with you.

Comment: Sure @HiltonGiesenow, This is in our roadmap, we will update you once it released.